# How to force calling paintComponent?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jlabel, paintcomponent

I have a JLabel with the paintComponent() overriden.I want it to be forcefully called since the code that updates my Label UI is this event.How can I force its calling and updating of UI? (by the way,repaint does not work!)

here is my code :

```
BufferedImage background;
String Uri;

public CustomClockLabel(String Uri){
    init(Uri);
    this.Uri = Uri;
}

public void init(String Uri){
    try {
        URL inp = CustomClockLabel.class.getResource(Uri);
        background = ImageIO.read(inp);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    if(background != null){
        g2.drawImage(background, 0, 0,getWidth(),getHeight(), this);
    }
    g2.dispose();
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

here is the code that updates labels and it is called recursively :

```
lblHour1 = new CustomClockLabel("/icons/noa_en/"+Hour.charAt(0)+".png");
lblHour1.repaint();
lblHour2 = new CustomClockLabel("/icons/noa_en/"+Hour.charAt(1)+".png");
lblHour2.repaint();
lblMin1 = new CustomClockLabel("/icons/noa_en/"+Minute.charAt(0)+".png");
lblMin1.repaint();
lblMin2 = new CustomClockLabel("/icons/noa_en/"+Minute.charAt(1)+".png");
lblMin1.repaint();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be under the false impression that creating new labels will update what's on the screen, doing this...

```
lblHour1 = new CustomClockLabel("/icons/noa_en/"+Hour.charAt(0)+".png");
lblHour2 = new CustomClockLabel("/icons/noa_en/"+Hour.charAt(1)+".png");
lblMin1 = new CustomClockLabel("/icons/noa_en/"+Minute.charAt(0)+".png");
lblMin2 = new CustomClockLabel("/icons/noa_en/"+Minute.charAt(1)+".png");
```

Will change the reference of the variables, so they will no longer be the same variables as those you added to the screen.

Assuming that the above variables have being added to the screen already, you could simply update them by using something like...

```
lblHour1.init(new ImageIcon("/icons/noa_en/"+Hour.charAt(0)+".png"));
lblHour2.init(new ImageIcon("/icons/noa_en/"+Hour.charAt(1)+".png"));
lblMin1.init(new ImageIcon("/icons/noa_en/"+Minute.charAt(0)+".png"));
lblMin2.init(new ImageIcon("/icons/noa_en/"+Minute.charAt(1)+".png"));
revalidate();
repaint();
```

If that fails, you should try setting one the labels border's properties so you can see if it's actually been added to the screen.

**Updated**

After some experimentation with what little you code you have made available, here are some more recommendations...

1. As has already being mentioned, make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent` first, as one of the jobs of this method is to clear the graphics ready for painting...
2. Make sure you provide a suitable sizing hint to the component, so the layout managers have some kind of idea of how big you might like the component to be.  This ensures that the component is not sized to `0x0`

The following example is very simple, but takes (what little) code you supplied and builds a runnable example from it...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class PaintComponentTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PaintComponentTest();
    }

    private int time = 0;

    public PaintComponentTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                final CustomClockLabel counter = new CustomClockLabel("/icons/0.png");
                Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        time++;
                        if (time > 9) {
                            time = 0;
                        }
                        counter.init("/icons/" + Integer.toString(time) + ".png");
                        counter.repaint();
                    }
                });
                timer.start();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(counter);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class CustomClockLabel extends JPanel {

        BufferedImage background;
        String Uri;

        public CustomClockLabel(String Uri) {
            init(Uri);
            this.Uri = Uri;
        }

        public void init(String Uri) {
            try {
                URL inp = getClass().getResource(Uri);
                background = ImageIO.read(inp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            if (background != null) {
                g2.drawImage(background, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
            }
            g2.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `repaint()` on the component in question will force it to paint again.

The problem you have does not appear to repainting, as you are actually changing the labels on the panel. Make sure you remove the old labels and add the new ones instead and call `revalidate()`. (The code you posted looks like you are just updating the label references and not actually changing them out on the panel.)

Overall, the design could be improved dramatically by making your `CustomClockLabel` class take in a parameter that changes the image and therefore allows you to just call repaint().

Comment: how do you try to `repait()` your labels? It must work for you.

Comment: I did added repaint in the code,but it didn't work.even revalidating it did not change.

Comment: Did you remove and add components before revalidating? If not there is nothing new to validate.

Comment: Since I'm using group layout if I remove it,it messes up my UI.

Comment: Which is exactly why I mentioned you really have a poor design issue and that could be improved by making your clock components change their display based on a method call instead of having to create a new object each update.

Comment: Okay,maybe I should change the design.

Answer (score 2):

```
lblHour1 = new CustomClockLabel("/icons/noa_en/"+Hour.charAt(0)+".png");
```

The above code doesn't do anything. All is does is create a new component. But that component is not added to the GUI so it obviously doesn't repaint.

There is nothing in your class that would cause it to need repainting, so your question doesn't make sense. You have a design problem. I don't see any reason to create a custom label.

If you want to change the image, then just use a standard JLabel with an Icon. Then to change the image you just use the `setIcon(...)` method and the label will repaint itself automatically.

Comment: setIcon is not an option because of design choices made.also see changes I made to the code

Comment: @armin, did you read my answer? I told you what the problem is. `Don't create a new component`. It is a wast of resource and based on your code you already have a reference to the label. Instead you should  update the property of an existing component. So you need a method like "changeImage(...)`. Inside that method you save the image and then invoke `repaint()` inside the method. The external code should NOT invoke the repaint(). I was just going to make a comment about your design choices but MadProgramer beat me to it.

Comment: @camickr yes,I know,will redesign it now.Looks like the is no other way.

Answer (score 2):

> (by the way,repaint does not work!)

If it isn't, then the only thing i can suspect, the fault is in your painting order: where you are calling `super.paintComponent(g);` after you are drawing the image. If your label is non-opaque and has background color, then you will not see the image, as the later painting `super.paintComponent(g)` will be drawn above the previous painting.

**Try changing the order:**

```
super.paintComponent(g);

Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

if(background != null){
    g2.drawImage(background, 0, 0,getWidth(),getHeight(), this);
}
g2.dispose();
```

Comment: long time no see. How do you do?

Comment: @MadProgrammer please where (and how is that possible that you had) you found available time for something funny as are/is hollydays

Comment: @armin, even if that doesn't work, that is also an issue you might well face. Anyway, try change your design as others have suggested. You can't expect a thing to work, if don't do it in the right way.

Comment: @mKorbel Actually, it's more like my wife is on holidays (she's a full time mum), so I get to take care of our daughter instead ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer whats holly... whats ??? this isn't hollydays :-), I have one year old twins, two bees that fly fundamentally to opposite direction